# Asp.net Page controls and viewstate

Tags: asp.net, viewstate

if i set `EnableViewState="false"` then also input data is maintain after postback at the time of using control like

- textbox
- radio button
- checkbox
- etc.

So I just wanted to know bit internal things that if `EnableViewState="false"` then how input data is maintain after postback when we are using control like textbox, radio button checkbox etc. please discuss the internal issue.

Thanks.

### here is my aspx code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" EnableViewState="false" CodeBehind="WebForm2.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication1.WebForm2" %>
```

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" 
        style="position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;"></asp:TextBox>


    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox2" runat="server" 
        style="position: absolute; top: 66px; left: 11px; z-index: 1;"></asp:TextBox>


<asp:RadioButton ID="RadioButton1" runat="server" style="position: relative" />

    <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" style="position: relative" />

 &nbsp;<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" />

 </div>

</form>
```

Comment: see this post http://aspadvice.com/blogs/joteke/archive/2004/03/15/2273.aspx that offers the explanation.

Comment: I have an updated answer with some references and example. Do you have any suggestions / question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Input data is maintained because the browser sends the input data to the server on every postback. For example, the textbox on the page has its text sent to the server *every time there is a postback*. Therefore, the text property does not need to be stored in view state in order to be remembered across postbacks.

For much more information on view state, check out this article: [Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [Server controls persist their state when EnableViewState is set to False](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316813)

**Example**: Consider backcolor setting programmatically. On postback, if viewstate is switched off, the `background color` of the Textbox control is lost. However, the text value of the control is maintained.

Note: If the backcolor was set directly in markup rather than in code behind, it would have persisted.

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<asp:TextBox ID="Textbox1" runat="server"  EnableViewState="false"></asp:TextBox>
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" EnableViewState="false" />
</form>

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
        this.Textbox1.BackColor = Color.Yellow;

    }
}
```

---

Also refer

1. [Understanding ASP.NET View State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972976.aspx)
2. [View State for TextBox and other controls that implement IPostBackDataHandler](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/378180/View-State-for-TextBox-and-other-controls-that-imp)
3. [How do I disable viewstate for a specific control?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4756590/how-do-i-disable-viewstate-for-a-specific-control?rq=1)