# Visual Studios C# - Class re-called on page refresh

Tags: c#, visual-studio

In Visual studios, is the class recalled every time the page refreshes? I have the following class - I want to add value to a variable every time a button is clicked;

```
public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    Random random = new Random();
    int total;
    int playerTotalValue;

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    }
    protected void ranPlayer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int randomNumTwo = random.Next(1, 10);
        playerTotalValue = playerTotalValue + randomNumTwo; //playerTotalValue gets reset to zero on every click
        playerTotal.Text = playerTotalValue.ToString();
    }
}
```

playerTotalValue gets resets to zero every time I click 'ranPlayer' button, or this is what I think happens.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**HTTP is stateless**. That means it will not retain the values in the variable like you do in windows form programming. So whenever you click on the button it executes the same way as it loaded in the initial page loading. But wait !. You have the value available in the text box. So you can read the value from there and store it in the variable.

```
    protected void ranPlayer_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        playerTotalValue =0;
        if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(playerTotal.Text))
        {
          playerTotalValue =Convert.ToInt32(playerTotal.Text);
        }
        int randomNumTwo = random.Next(1, 10);
        playerTotalValue = playerTotalValue + randomNumTwo; //playerTotalValue gets reset to zero on every click
        playerTotal.Text = playerTotalValue.ToString();
     }
```

Comment: asp.net TextBox control is not dependent on viewstate as its data is available on the form post, therefore it can maintain state across postbacks without viewstate. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1475806/asp-net-how-viewstate-works

Comment: @Shay: You are correct. I realized the mistake and removed that statement from my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

The duration of this instance is the **request**. After that it is discarded. Every request will use separate objects.

Any state you need to preserve between requests must be either part of the request (for example an http form field or cookie), or held at the server (session-state).

So yes: `playerTotalValue` is 0 at the start of each request.

Answer (score 0):

I would create a property that will be storing the value in a ViewState so the value will be preserved on postbacks.